# Personalize List Columns - Nodejs(NPM)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, npm

I am looking for an npm module to select column from one table to another or from one div to another. I have tried various examples but none of them works well, I have attached a screenshot for the solution which I am seeking.

[image]

Comment: Yikes, for something that complex I'd recommend you pick up an entire JS framework... If you use [`vue`](https://vuejs.org/) there are several vue components that I've come across that were built for exactly this. Might be a lot of boilerplate starting out, but if you're going to be building complex interfaces like this, it'll pay off quickly. Otherwise, there's no short code snippet for what you're looking for.

Comment: But I am sure there might be some npm module for this, not to complete the entire functionality but at least to select an item from one column and to push it to others.

Comment: potentially there is, but nowadays there aren't a lot of standalone JS widgets being developed. Most modern solutions will be in the form of a component for either `React`, `Vue` or `Angular`. I'm still willing to wager you would benefit greatly from picking up  JS framework if you're making user interfaces that are this intricate.

Comment: I have received the example, including a link for someone looking the same solution - https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-rearrangeable.html

Answer (score 1):

I had found the npm module which I am looking for, at last, I am sharing the link for that too in case someone also finding the same node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect